# How to handle multiple configurations using chef

Tags: configuration, chef-infra, roles, multiple-instances, cookbook

I have a web objects application that runs on multiple ports (around 20 ports) on each host.

For each port there is a different set of start up parameters ( eg different java_opts for each port. So each host will have 20 sets of  "port - java_opts" combination ).

In my production environment, I have 40 such hosts.

I have written a chef cookbook to deploy this app but i am unable to figure out how to handle different java_opts for each port across all these hosts.

1.How can I handle this in chef.
2. I also want to have the ability to handle these java_opts dynamically. ie during a situation, I should be able to pass a different set of java_opts to a host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) in Chef? Assuming your nodes are connected to Chef server, you should be able to create an attribute "Java_ops port" for each host with a value of the desired ports. Another option is to use [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html), but I think your situation is better suited for attributes.